# click event is not working in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

We have implemented the Autodesk Forge Viewer in our web application. We have displayed the Navisworks file in Forge Viewer.

On clicking the particular element/object in forge viewer, we need to get the Object ID of selected element.

We will use this Object ID for multiple purpose (like zooming, etc) in our application.

For this we have used the below selection changed event in our page but the below event is not working.

```
 EventsTutorial.prototype.onSelectionEvent = function(event){
var currSelection = this.viewer.getSelection();
var domElem = document.getElementById('MySelectionValue');
domElem.innerText = currSelection.length;
};
```

Kindly help us to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't register your function as a listener to the viewer. So I guess your function `onSelectionEvent` is never called.

You probably want to register a listener to either the `SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`[(docs)](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/#selection-changed-event) or the `AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT`[(docs)](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/#aggregate-selection-changed-event).

```js
this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, (args) => {
     // do something
});
```